# How to divide total days into different year so that it doesn't skew the dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I previously asked a question. Iam looking for distribution totaldays taken to process request. some of the request were processed in years and skewing the dataset. following is the example:

```
Req no.       Year       ReceivedDate      ClosedDate              TotalDays
1              2011      2011-01-05                                   NA
1              2012      2011-01-05                                   NA
1              2013      2011-01-05         2013-08-12                950
```

Here we have same request that took three years to process. I can get totaldays to process by simply subtracting receivedate from closedDate however it lands on closed year 2013 whereas it is suppose to be 350+ days in 2011, 365 in 2012 and rest in 2013. Hopefully this clears the confusion.

```
Req no.   Year     ReceivedDate     Yearend        ClosedDate      TotalDays   TotalDaysinYear
1         2011      2011-01-05      2011-12-31          NA            NA           357
1         2012      2011-01-05      2012-12-31          NA            NA           365
1         2013      2011-01-05      2013-12-31          2013-8-1      950          223
```

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: (df.Receive-df.Yearend).dt.days ?

Comment: Iam trying to divide 950 days into three years so that it doesn't skew the distribution.

Comment: Why is TotalDaysinYear is 357 in row 1 and 365 in row 2 -- when they both have the same ReceivedDate and Yearend Date? I think you need to provide more information in terms of the logic that you want to implement if anyone is going to be able to assist you.

Comment: @DavidErickson i have explained it more hopefully it clears the confusion.

Comment: @ganeshghimire it's still not possible for someone to infer where you are getting 357 from versus 365 from based off the new, edited post.

Comment: @DavidErickson what i was trying to acheive is if case was not touched in whole year than give value of 365 days else ReceiveDate minus the YearStart or ClosedDate minus the YearStart